# Does Chrome OS use an initramfs?

Tags: chrome

Chrome OS uses dm-verity to verify the root partition on Chromebooks and it uses a kernel command line parameter, `dm`,  to receive the arguments used by dm-verity. How can it process these arguments, which look to be the kind used for `veritysetup` without an initrd or an initramfs? I know that it does not use an initrd, but does the kernel contain an initramfs?

Answer (score 1):

No.

[[dm-devel] [PATCH v5 0/3] init: add support to directly boot to a mapped device](https://www.redhat.com/archives/dm-devel/2016-February/msg00199.html)